How to configure network settings for apt on Raspberry Pi?
I picked up my raspberry pi for the first time since moving into a dorm, and apt has completely broken. It seems like maybe a firewall issue but I'm not entirely sure. I referred to this
article but none of the logical fixes worked.
I switched from Wifi, to Ethernet, to a LAN directly between my PC and the pi, and I still got some variation of the following errors.
sudo apt-get update yields :
rector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch InRelease
Err:2 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

apt upgrade has so many 404 errors its not even worth putting it on here but heres a couple:
b9u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/u/udisks2/udisks2_2.1.8-1+deb9u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/u/unzip/unzip_6.0-21+deb9u2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/u/usbutils/usbutils_007-4+deb9u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

This is pretty much the same no matter what I'm trying to download.
I also tried deb [trusted=yes] in sources.list and this had no effect.
Then --allow-unauthenticated which also had no effect.
I'm pretty much completely at a loss here so if any more information is needed please ask.

Starting with the initial 404 Not Found error:

E: The repository 'http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch Release' does no longer have a Release file.

That's usually not a "network" issue, except in cases when your connection uses the browser-based network login system. In this case though, we can visit the URL in a browser and navigate to dists/stretch/ – the full URL is http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/stretch/ – and you'll see that there actually isn't a Release file in that location anymore. So the "404 Not Found" is completely legitimate.
Most likely this is because Raspbian Stretch is a 2017 release, 3 releases behind current (i.e. it's not even "oldoldstable" anymore), and some distributions just don't keep old releases around forever in their mirrors. For example, Debian moves them out of their main mirrors system into a separate archive server, but I could not find such a server for Raspbian.
With the main 'Release' file being missing, it is natural that the individual package files will also be missing; they're the ones that occupy the disk space, after all.
So given that the repository for Raspbian Stretch is gone, you only have two options: a) apt-upgrade to a newer Raspbian release or b) fresh install a newer Raspbian release. Stretch was followed by Buster (then Bullseye, then Bookworm), so you could try to edit your /etc/apt/sources.list and replace all mentions of 'stretch' with 'buster' and do an apt full-upgrade to upgrade to the new release; then repeat it again for bullseye and so on. (Skipping one may be supported; skipping two definitely is not supported.)

@Gantendo: Unlike what some people say in comments, "we" don't have a rule about not supporting older systems. OP can decide whether it's worth their effort or not.

Why was this downvoted?  Seems like a fairly correct answer to me.  Certainly the issue is not with apt, rather its that the repo is not valid anymore.

Sometimes you might have things you might not want to set up from scratch. I have Ubuntu machines that have gone 2-3 LTSes upgraded cause I didn't have a good reason to rebuild.  And an important thing here is it is an answer, not a comment explaining what's actually broken and why

A fresh start isn't viable for me as I don't have a machine that can read SD cards, so this was a perfect response, thanks.

Well, regarding that, I'd say that a USB SD card reader is pretty much required when dealing with Raspberry Pi and such... (though don't most laptops have one?) I do kind of remember newer Pi's having a way to boot into "Mass storage" mode, but that might be a much newer feature than yours.

https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#raspberry-pi-boot-modes 2+ apparently, the OG one won't if I recall though, I had mine set up to boot from SD  card, but had the install on a USB HDD
